# Using float when methods require int arguments?

Tags: java

I'm writing a game in java where asteroids fly across the screen to hit a spaceship. The speed of the asteroids is a float, but the X and Y values of each asteroid is an integer. As a result, the movement of the asteroids jumps every time the speed reaches a new integer value. 
I can't use float or double values for the X and Y values because the rectangle class I need for collision requires ints as arguments.

I tried a function using doubles so I could use the ceiling function,

```
    public static int doubleToInt(double d){
    int i = Math.ceil(d);       
}
```

but this too gave an issue with converting into integers. Is there a better way to do this?

edit: the applicable code for the asteroid class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Asteroid {
// the main enemy class of the game, an asteroid!
// these are generated through a for loop in the main game loop.
int x ;
int y ;
int r = 4; // radius of each asteroid. 
static float speed = 1;; // speed of asteroids, increases as time goes by.

void move(Asteroid rock){
    if(hasReachedBottom(rock)){
        //rock.x = randInt(520,550); // random to start, so that the asteroids may be offset a bit.
        //rock.y = randInt(0,Game.theGame.getHeight()); // y position, constant for each asteroid. Casted as an int. random number
        initAsteroids(rock,rock.r + 500,501 + rock.r );// this range is for after the asteroids spawn.
        //rock.x = 100;
    }
    x -= speed;
}

private boolean hasReachedBottom(Asteroid rock){
    if(rock.x + rock.r < 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
        }

}
void paint(Graphics2D g){ // render an asteroid
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(x, y, r, r);
}

public Rectangle getBounds(Asteroid rock){
    return new Rectangle(rock.x,rock.y,rock.r,rock.r);

}
```

}

Comment: can you post the position update for asteroid? "As a result, the movement of the asteroids jumps every time the speed reaches a new integer value" -> if that happens pixel by pixel it shouldn't jump neither be 'jerky'. Maybe there is a multiplication/division wrongly rounded to int before the actual rectangle placing and that makes the movement jerky

Comment: Why does this give too much of an issue?  The pixels on the screen are discrete.  You can't draw in between the pixels on the screen.  BTW I would use Math.round(d) or plain `(int) d`

Comment: round and int cast don't always do the same thing - could be problematic depending on the resolution of the game space

Comment: I assume you float values are close to 1 or less.  If you have a float value of say 10, you should expect the astorid to just 10 pixels each time you add this.

Comment: The description is not sufficient for a really *profound* answer, but I'd recommend you to use `float` or prefarably `double` for the x/y part of the coordinates, and only cast them to `int` "as late as possible" (that is, when you want to pass them to your rectangle constructor). BTW: If this is about Swing, then you could even consider using `Rectangle2D` instead of `Rectangle`, and you would not have this issue at all.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Though you can't draw pixels in between the screen, there would be a slower ramp up of speed, rather than simply moving from 1 pixel / 10 ticks to 2 pixels per 10 ticks.

Comment: @fostythesnowman N pixels per 10 ticks might be jumpy.  How about 0.1 pixels per tick or 0.2 pixels per tick? i.e. 1 pixel per 5 ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cast a double to an int you can just:

```
int i = (int)d;
```

If you take a look at this you can see what will happen in a case of double numbers from 0 to 2:

```
    for(double d = 0; d < 2; d+=0.1) {
        System.out.print((int)d);
    }
```

Here is the print:

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

In your case the double (speed) will increase and affect the spaceship everytime it reaches a new integer. Which will have to be the case if your co-ordinate system is discrete.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply do:

```
int i = ((int)d); // cast to int - same like applying Math.floor()
i += (d-i > 0 ? 1 : 0); // in case the fraction part of the integer is bigger than zero, add 1 (ciel)
```

This is actually implementing the same behavior of `Math.ciel()`

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a `double` to an `int` is a [narrowing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3), so an implicit cast (what you had in your code) is not allowed by the language. If you explicitly state your intentions with a cast, the code will compile:

```
int i = (int) Math.ceil(d);
```

I have to say that your rounding method is a bit unusual, but if it's what you need, so be it. Some alternatives would be to use `Math.round(d)` and cast that, or round down by casting `d` to an `int`.

Comment: You can cast a double to int.

Comment: Oh, I'm terribly sorry, I didn't know the difference between implicit and explicit cast. I retract! :-) !

Comment: When I wrote the little method, I hadn't considered that there's a round function, I just thought of ceil and floor. That would certainly make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily mix floating point and integer math (in almost any language), only the compiler requires it to say explicitly when you desired type conversions that can potentially overflow.

A simple design would be to simply use float (or double) for the coordinates and just cast to int when you create the rectangle:

```
int i = (int) floatValue;
```

It really doesnt matter much which conversion method you chose, alternates would be Math.round(), floor() or ceil() - *as long as you use it consistently* everwhere (avoiding to compare apples to oranges).

Since the position is already encapsulted in your asteroid class and also the move method is on the asteroid class this shouldn't require many changes.

Answer (score 0):

Return type of Math.ceil(double) is double only. so better to use Double wrappper class of Double which has function to get int value of double and return the int value from intValue(), intValue method is internally doing typecasting to int ,the thing which already java is doing then why to write some additional code –
you can do like this.

```
Double k= Math.ceil(d);
int i=k.intValue();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Return type of Math.ceil(double) is double only.
so better to use Double wrappper class of Double which has function to get int value of double and return the int value from intValue()
intValue method is internally doing typecasting to int ,the thing which already java is doing then why to write some additional code

Comment: Put that in your answer, I mean.